# save csv data with different data type into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, csv

Hi guys i have trouble when trying to read and save a data from csv file to an array, i've been sucessful to read and save it into a char type data,but i need to save the number into a int data type,so i can use a math operation, can some one help me?

here's my csv file content:

```
Nama,Gaji,Zakat,Gaji Bersih
Ali,1234567,,
Sofyan,2345678,,
Kholimi,3456789,,
```

i also need to save also the "Nama,Gaji,Zakat,and Gaji Bersih" into an array.

Here's my code who only can save a content from csv file to char array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char buffer[1024] ;
   char *record,*line;
   char nama[10][100];
   int i=0,j=0,c=0,gaji[10][100],zakat[10][100],bersih[10][100];
   int mat[100][100];
   FILE *fstream = fopen("Tugas03.csv","r");
   if(fstream == NULL)
   {
      printf("\n file opening failed ");
      return -1;
   }
   while((line=fgets(buffer,1024,fstream))!=NULL)
   {
     record = strtok(line,",");
     while(record != NULL){
       strcpy(nama[c], record);
       c++;
       printf("\t%s",record);
       mat[i][j++] = atoi(record) ;
       record = strtok(NULL,",");
     }
     ++i ;
   }
   return 0 ;
 }
```

some one help me please...

Here's my new code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char buffer[1024] ;
   char *record,*line;
   char nama[10][100],temp[100];
   int i=0,j=0,c=0,gaji[10][100],zakat[10][100],bersih[10][100];
   int mat[100][100];
   FILE *fstream = fopen("Tugas03.csv","r");
   if(fstream == NULL)
   {
      printf("\n file opening failed ");
      return -1;
   }
   while((line=fgets(buffer,1024,fstream))!=NULL)
   {
     record = strtok(line,",");
     while(record != NULL){
       if(c==0||1||2||3||4||8||12){
        strcpy(nama[c], record);
       }else if(c==5||9||13){
        strcpy(temp, record);
        gaji[c][100] = atoi(temp);
       }
       c++;
       //printf("\t%s",record);
       mat[i][j++] = atoi(record) ;
       record = strtok(NULL,",");
     }
     ++i ;
   }
   printf("\t%s\n", gaji[0]);
   printf("\t%s\n", nama[0]);
   printf("\t%s\n", temp);
   return 0 ;
 }
```

Comment: In your case the first `atoi` failed. In every line the first record is a `name`. Did you notice it?

Comment: i've been trying to use atoi but it doesnt work

Comment: `c==0||1||2||3||4||8||12` interestingly this condition is always true. :)

Comment: c==0||c==1||c==2||c==3||c==4||c==8||c==12
how about this?

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet.: Yes this is good but code is too closely dependent on the data that is being read.

Comment: <code>strcpy(temp, record);
        gaji[c][100] = atoi(temp);<code>

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet.: Clarify in the question what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: i am trying to convert a char array into int,

Comment: I know this isn’t directly relevant, but since using python for all sorts of text processing including csv read/write the thought of processing csv in C sounds less attractive than sticking needles in my own eyes.

Comment: @4386427 after i convert it,i want to save it to an array

Comment: @NeiosFlameStuxnet Answer updated with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty unclear how you want to have the data stored so it's difficult to help you.

But this is a major problem:

> You need to set `j` back to zero in every loop.

Like:

```
   while((line=fgets(buffer,1024,fstream))!=NULL)
   {
     j = 0;  // Add this line

     record = strtok(line,",");
     while(record != NULL){
       strcpy(nama[c], record);
       c++;
       printf("\t%s",record);
       printf(" (%d)", atoi(record));  // For test add this line
       mat[i][j++] = atoi(record) ;
       record = strtok(NULL,",");
     }
     ++i ;
   }
```

If you run the above code with this in the input file:

```
N,G,Z,GB
A,1,2,3
B,4,5,6
C,7,8,9
```

you'll get:

```
    N (0)   G (0)   Z (0)   GB (0)
    A (0)   1 (1)   2 (2)   3 (3)
    B (0)   4 (4)   5 (5)   6 (6)
    C (0)   7 (7)   8 (8)   9 (9)
```

So as you can see, the numbers have been converted to `int` as you want.

The problem with this code is that it tries to convert every token (i.e. both names and numbers) to `int`. You can do it but it's probably not what you want. If not, you need to redesign your code.

Step 1 is to make a clear plan for how you want to store data.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
struct data {
    char nama[100];
    int Gaji;
    int Zakat;
    int Gaji_Bersih;
};
```

to store the lines (other than the heading)

Notice that `strtok` is a bad choice for this kind of parsing as it skips empty tokens.